# Ellipsis Switch Case Visual Studio Equivalent

Tags: c++, switch-statement, ellipsis

I am trying to write a switch statement case that identifies all numbers from 0 to 9 in textual form. In gcc I believe it is possible to use the statement case '0'...'9':

Is there an equivalent expression that would work in Microsoft Visual Studio or will I have to write a separate case for each number?

Comment: `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` no switch needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I an trying to add it to a switch statement that already contains several cases :(

Answer (score 1):

> In gcc I believe it is possible to use the statement case '0'...'9'

Yes, but this is an extension of the GNU C Compiler, it is not C++ standard.

I think the best way to do that is to write something like that:

```
switch(c) {
  case '0':
  case '1':
  case '2':
  //...
  case '9':
    //Do something
  break;
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
switch(c) {
  case '0': case '1': case '2': /*...*/ case '9':
    //Do something
  break;
}
```

(Note the spaces between `:` and the following `case`)